# Implement audio/video streaming support using WebRTC on mobile and web platform

Tags: android, webrtc

I want to stream audio/video to the web using WebRTC and at same time want to store/record audio/video in local. is it possible?

If there any example for the same, please give url.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MediaRecorder API](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) to record a copy of the MediaStream from the camera.  It can be used in Firefox (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API)). Chrome only has an Intent To Implement for MediaRecorder; right now various workarounds have to be used to roughly emulate it; see [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/)